# Local database systems for simple application

Tags: database

I have been thinking of making a program to use in my company. I would like to store information in a (local) database and use this to keep track of the payments of my clients. I am most experienced in programming in Java. Do you have any suggestions for these databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are probably looking for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). It is very light, basic, works with SQL,but doesn’t have any built in relational methods to link multiple tables together(JOINS, etc). As you mentioned you’ll be using Java, here’s the [SQLITEJDBCPackage](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc). Also, here’s a [blog](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/) that can help you get started.

On the other hand, there is a wide variety of databases present in the market like:

1. [RDBMS](https://www.javatpoint.com/what-is-rdbms): [MySQL](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database), [PostgresSQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_java.htm)
2. [NoSQL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-nosql/): [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-java-part-i)(can run on cloud and locally), [Neo4J](https://neo4j.com/developer/java/)
3. [Time Series Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database)(If you storing IOT or time dependant data): [InfluxDB](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java)
4. [Cloud Databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_database)(Might not be relevant to you since you want a local setup, but just to help you understand better): [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/server/samples-java), Neo4J, MongoDB, AWS RDS, etc.

Comment: An upvote would help out too you know.